# R unable to find an inherited method for function 'itemFrequency' for signature '"data.frame"'

Tags: r

I have a df named 'a' and with the following command:

```
 freq <- itemFrequency(a, weighted = FALSE)
```

which gives an

> error:unable to find an inherited method for function 'itemFrequency' for signature '"data.frame"'

There doesn't seem to be any hint as to what this is anywhere online.
 R documentations states that a must be an object, which a data frame is.

Found: df has to be converted into item matrix like so:

`a1 <- as(a, "transactions`")

and then used in  itemFrequency.

Comment: What package is the `itemFrequency` function from?

Comment: It is from the arules package. There is no itemFrequency in standard R, right?

Comment: Because `itemFrequency` is a generic function, it takes anything, but a generic function just dispatches to different versions based on what's passed. There needs to be a class-specific function in order to "work". You can see the valid methods with `methods(itemFrequency)`. From there you can see it's only set up to work with `temMatrix` and `tidLists` objects. There is no definition for `data.frame` objects.

Comment: So if I: data <- as(a, "transactions") it should work? as I convert into Item Matrix?

Comment: I have similar issues working on RStudio: > library(arules)
> library(Matrix)
> library(lattice)
> library(arulesViz)
> summary(votes)
      republican  n       y       n.1     y.1    
 democrat  :267   ?: 12   ?: 48   ?: 11   ?: 11  
 republican:167   n:235   n:192   n:170   n:247  
                  y:187   y:194   y:253   y:176

   
  
> itemFrequency(votes, type="absolute")
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘itemFrequency’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to implement Apriori algorithm.

To find the itemFrequency of the items in your data set

> itemFrequency(mydata) 
>   Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function "itemFrequency", for signature "data.frame"

Solution:
step1. load the necessary packages and library like arules, arulesViz
step2. Let say you trying to bring votes data and you need to read the data as transactions

> votes <- read.transactions("~/Desktop/votes.csv")
>   if you just write votes you will have a summary of your transactions as follow
>   votes
>   transactions in sparse format with
>    435 transactions (rows) and
>    342 items (columns)

Now you can easily find the itemFrequency

> itemFrequency(votes)
>   Here is a sample image
>
> itemFrequency(votes)
>     democrat 245
>   republican 
>   345

Hope this will help!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21803869)

Comment: Hi @anothermh, thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. [Images of code are not appropriate on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, anothermh!